# Stephen Anderson's workshop about information visualization in Amsterdam - Sponsorship Proposal

Tags: discussion, events

> **Note:**  If you want SE to sponsor your ticket, you have to do something in return. Post an answer to this question illustrating why
>   *you* should go and what the community will get out of it. For example: you'll blog about it on the UX.SE blog and contribute answers
>   to the info-visualisation tag as well as spreading our community's
>   existence around amongst event attendees.

## [image: Stephen Anderson's The Quest for Emotional Engagement: Information Visualization]

My company Q42 and our partnered design firm Fabrique are organising a full-day workshop in Amsterdam together with speaker and designer Stephen Anderson, whom many UX designers should surely know from his book, Seductive Interaction Design. His new workshop is all about information visualization and since we're organising I'd like to offer members of the UX.SE community a discounted ticket to attend the event.

Send me a note if you want to come and I'll give you a code you can use to activate the discount. You can read about the event, which takes place on November 9th, and buy a ticket from here: http://qfee.nl

OR!

Another alternative is that Stack Exchange sponsors UX members attending. If you're interested in that, post here. Hopefully the SE community team will be paying attention ;-)

[image: Photo of the event location]

## Why you should be there

- Stephen Anderson's talks are among the best you can find in user experience design. You truly learn something each time; he's really good at connecting theory to practice and showing you plenty of examples you can use. Since this is a full-day workshop, there'll be plenty of time to digest what he's talking about and (presumably) try things out for yourself. His book is a must-read if you care about user-centered design and his Mental Notes cards are a great help during brainstorming sessions and for product designers trying to tackle tough product challenges (I'm speaking from experience here).
- Network! Spending the whole day with people from around the Amsterdam area is a great way to meet and connect with potential customers, employees, and people to follow on Twitter. Plus, meet me and our interaction engineering team from [Q42](http://q42.com) and designers from one of the Netherlands' best design firms, [Fabrique](http://fabrique.nl). And, hopefully, it's a chance to finally meet some other UX.SE members, if more than one of you chooses to come ;-)
- Since it's a Friday, why not combine the workshop with a long weekend in Amsterdam? Bring the partner along and check out the city while you're here.
- Dinner afterwards! Whoever sticks around after the workshop can join us for dinner at the restaurant around the corner and chat with us, Stephen, and your fellow attendees about all the great stuff you learned during the day.

## How much will it cost me?

- Tickets for the event are €300 for UX.SE members. That's a 40% discount!
- A flight from London to Amsterdam should be around €150 and Amsterdam is one train stop from the airport (around €10).
- One night in a hotel will clock you around €150-200 in Amsterdam city, but it's worth it since the city is so beautiful (especially during the winter months). Make extra use of that room by dragging your partner along to share the bed ;-)

Comment: Hey, this sounds awesome! If anyone would like to be sponsored for the conference, just [follow the directions in this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference/132283#132283) and make sure Rahul pings us employees to follow up. :)

Comment: This is great. Will try to come.

Comment: @spunkypixels Great! Do you mean you'll buy a ticket or that you want to get SE to sponsor you?

Answer (score 3):

Thats sounds cool! I'd love to join.

I'm busy designing and building a learning platform and insight in your own learning process plays an important role in the learning itself. There is all this information we can gather, but what makes sense to the user is a whole other story. And a very interesting one. I rather go beyond the usual web 2.0 goal setting and tracking. Getting more into visualization of useful data that you didn't think of from the beginning.

So... How can I join? Is there anything I need to do to get the sponsorship? I could offer photos and a blog post in return for example?

Comment: Cool, Lode! Aarthi mentioned in a comment above what your next steps are, see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference/132283#132283 .

Comment: Hmm, what about the `We need at least a month’s lead time to help you get your approval.`?

Comment: I guess we'll have to be creative. Since I'm the event organiser things should be smoother than with a 3rd party.

Comment: OK, it looks like you need to provide much more information about why you want to go, what the UX.SE community will get out of it, and why you're the one to go as opposed to someone else (there is no one else right now, but try anyway)